# classes/Logger.php / PHP Error

Tags: php, html, function, codeigniter

> CodeIgniter:
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen(scanner/logs/eventlogs_2018-05-06.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: classes/Logger.php

Logger.php

```
<?php

class Logger{

    private $logFile;
    private $fp;

    public function lfile($path) {
        $this->logFile = $path;
    }

    public function lwrite($message){

        if(!$this->fp) 
            $this->lopen();
        $scriptName = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $time = date('H:i:s:ms');
        fwrite($this->fp, "$time ,$scriptName, $message\n");
    }

    private function lopen(){

        $lfile = $this->logFile;
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $this->fp = fopen($lfile . '_' . $today . '.txt', 'a') or exit("Can't open $lfile!");
    }
}
?>
```

Bear in mind that my directory is not /scanner/logs/eventlogs/ but its /application/user/views/scanner/  so I have no idea why logger is trying to fopen there... Can anyone help?

I am using this as a form to web scan!
a snippet

```html
$log = new Logger();
   $log->lfile('scanner/logs/eventlogs'); // THIS IS WHERE ERROR POPS UP

   $log->lwrite('Connecting to database');

   $connectionFlag = connectToDb($db);

   if(!$connectionFlag)
   {
    $log->lwrite('Error connecting to database');
    echo 'Error connecting to database';
    return;
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any path logic except for `$lfile` which is defined in `lfile()` so let's see how your calling that (and post how you are generally using this as well).

Comment: Exactly what I mean.Here's the full error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(scanner/logs/eventlogs_2018-05-07.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: classes/Logger.php

Line Number: 66

Backtrace:

File: /home/cesspool/public_html/application/views/user/scanner/classes/Logger.php
Line: 66
Function: fopen

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm getting at, but thats ok ill explain in a sec. Can you first provide me with an example of how you are using this (**as an edit to the post**).

Comment: done buddy, please check and thanks!

Comment: Nevermind. $log->lfile('scanner/logs/eventlogs'); found the error!! I should've added directories here too! Thanks again!

Comment: I think that was what I was getting at. Check my answer if that was it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this function (which seems to set the path for the other functions):

```
public function lfile($path) {
    $this->logFile = $path;
}
```

To something like:

```
public function lfile($path) {
    $this->logFile = FCPATH . $path;
}
```

This way all your paths will be from `C:\xampp\htdocs\` (FCPATH example) and not depend on the current working directory where you are calling your function from.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__DIR__` constant, which returns the current directory of the script.

```
public function lfile($path) {
    $this->logFile = __DIR__ . "/" . $path; // sprintf("%s/%s", __DIR__, $path);
}
```

Learn more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php